# What is this small, bright yellow, mushroom found in the woods in Massachusetts?

Tags: united-states, walking, forests, fungi-identification, mushrooms

Last week, my husband was walking on a path beside a shallow brook in [Rutland State Park](https://www.mass.gov/locations/rutland-state-park), a wooded area in central Massachusetts, USA. He came across a bright yellow mushroom with a very short, white stem. It was very small, about 1 inch (2.5 cm) high and just a bit wider. The cap was fully rounded, almost bulb-like, and firm.  The stem was flexible, but not wanting to break it, he didn't bend it far enough to get a view from underneath.

As with all other items found in nature, it's important to leave things as they are, so he didn't pick it.

It was the only one of its type he saw on the two-mile path. What is this pretty mushroom?

*Click on photos for full size.*

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## *Bolbitius titubans*

Also known as *Bolbitius vitellinus*, that there looks to be a young **Yellow Field Cap**. They're quite small when they're yellow, but they quickly mature into taller, flatter, brownish mushroom.

[image]
[image]
[image]